# How do I force the user to use the front facing camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am developing a program that uses the camera. I am using media store to get the raw footage from the android camera.

I want the user to have to use the front facing camera, or at least open it front facing by default.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                      
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I have tried this, and another method of calling:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);                      
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Any ideas to why this isn't working? I am using it on an asus tablet.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

add these permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>


private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(storage);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(storage, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + storage + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting getOutputPhotoFile() ?

Comment: Im not asking how to store the image. I want to know how to make camera open using the front facing camera

Comment: My storage of the image, and the properties im taking from it is all fine. I just want to streamline it so it opens the front facing camera automatically

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user to have to use the front facing camera, or at least open it front facing by default.

Then you should be using the camera APIs directly or via [a wrapper library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created).

> Any ideas to why this isn't working?

You are launching a third-party camera app. There are hundreds of such apps, both pre-installed on devices and user-installed. There is no requirement for any camera app to honor random `Intent` extras, particularly ones that are not part of the Android SDK.